# mysql lock wait timeout: just try again without txn restart

Tags: mysql, timeout, locking

Many solutions on this site describe how to debug and fix a lock-wait timeout. They discuss changing `innodb_lock_wait_timeout` and figuring out the root cause.

The official error code states "try restarting transaction". My question is if I don't restart the transaction, is there any benefit to just retrying the query?

Comment: You can do that (if you didn't enable `innodb_rollback_on_timeout`). But it might just result in double (or infinite) waiting time, so it has a similar effect as increasing the timeout. You gain more control over the overall timeout, what codeparts (and what sessions) get repeated, stopped, skipped (e.g. if you actually don't care for that one single query in a 1h transaction) or exchanged by some other code - if you are willing to implement it. So if it is worth it depends on what you are doing, what you are trying to achieve by handling that yourself and, ultimately, the "root cause".

Comment: @Solarflare why comment instead of answer?